# 17-Across: Winner of next Sunday's Super Bowl LVI (!)

Tags: crosswords

If you're like me, you're excited for the big game this weekend. Here's a crossword puzzle to enjoy while we wait.

To solve in browser, I recommend accessing [this link](https://www.xwordinfo.com/Solve?secret=JYEwvAnADAjA7AMlAJjADnkA) from the east coast and [this link](https://www.xwordinfo.com/Solve?secret=JYEwvAnADAjAHAMlAJjAFmQZiA) from the west coast.

Here are the crossword details:

[image]

**Across**

1. Sultry scarf substitutes
5. Like Iron Man, not Elastigirl
10. Ariana Grande's "___ You"
11. Three-time Grammy-winning country rocker Steve
12. Patty/cake
13. Political opponent of Pericles, an anagram of CLONE
14. The Queen takes hers with milk
16. Palindromic attention-getting sound
17. Winner of next Sunday's Super Bowl LVI (!)
21. Sinus doc
22. "Who ___?", chant for 17-Across (maybe)
23. Talk ender
25. Chronicles aftermath
29. Cobbler, at times
30. It often occurs following a car wash, seemingly
31. Olympic blades
32. It might be tight or tough

**Down**

1. Race tag
2. Number of years Matthew Stafford has played for 17-Across (maybe)
3. What seven did to nine, in a joke
4. Cicada sound, depending
5. Punishment for a repeat offender
6. Different ending
7. Peggy, in Berlin
8. Expression of defeat
9. European teeth
15. Game concerned with flying formations
17. Word in a "Dear tenant" letter
18. ___ form (superb)
19. It's worth 1 point in Scrabble
20. They tend to accumulate in Central Park
24. Winner's sign
26. Microwave
27. Jesus weighs over 600 tons here
28. Picnic regular

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the solution!

> [image]

But wait!

> Turns out, both potential winning teams are valid solutions to the puzzle!
>  [image]

Turns out this puzzle is:

> one with two possible solutions based on the outcome of a future event, a type of puzzle famously exemplified (and possibly first done?) for the [1996 US election puzzle](https://www.crosswordunclued.com/2009/01/nyt-election-day-crossword.html) published in the NYT, and I believe repeated fairly recently there as well. Very fun and looking forward to the game!

Comment: Yeah, on Feb 6 2022 the NYT had a clue,  "the better of two sci-fi franchises." You could answer with either "Star Wars" or "Star Trek".

Answer (score 6):

The other answer already fills in the crossword, so in this answer, I wanted to highlight the

> Schrodinger/quantum/simultaneous clues/solutions.

Across:

> There is a single clue:
>  **17. Winner of next Sunday's Super Bowl LVI (!)**: *Los Angeles* / *Cincinnati*.  These are the two teams participating in Super Bowl LVI: the *Los Angeles* Rams and the *Cincinnati* Bengals.

Down (left to right):

> There are ten clues, one for each letter for the across clue, with each letter having two possibilities.
>  **17. Word in a "Dear tenant" letter**: *lease* / *cease*.  Presumably this is because the letter might be about the terms of the *lease*, or perhaps to tell the tenant to *cease* some activity.
>  **18. ___ form (superb)**: *on top* / *in top*.  "*in top* form" is a common phrasing; "*on top* form" is a little stilted, but [attested on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on+top+form%22).
>  **19. It's worth 1 point in Scrabble**: *s tile* / *n tile*.  There are ten one-point *tile*s in Scrabble, including all vowels as well as the consonants "l*n*r*s*t".
>  **4. Cicada sound, depending**: *soft "a"* / *soft "c"*.  The first "a" in "cicada" is pronounced as a *soft "a"* in some (but not all) pronunciations.  The first (but not second) "c" is a *soft "c"* (that is, pronounced like an "s") in all pronunciations.
>  **15. Game concerned with flying formations**: *Ender's* / *eiders*.  "*Ender's* Game" is a short story, novel, film, and more where the main character, Ender, plays a "game" that involves formations in space.  *Eiders* are ducks that are hunted (hence game), live in large colonies, and fly in formation.
>  **5. Punishment for a repeat offender**: *recage* / *recane*.  This is a bit of a stretch, but amusing.  Prisoners can be *cage*d or *cane*d, and presumably if they offend repeatedly, this may be done multiple times.
>  **20. They tend to accumulate in Central Park**: *eyers* / *NYers*.  Apparently "*eyers*" is a word synonymous with onlookers or observers.  Meanwhile, residents of New York might be called *NYers*.  I guess people-watchers in New York City might go to Central Park.
>  **7. Peggy, in Berlin**: *Gretl* / *Greta*.  Peggy is a diminutive form of Margaret in English.  The German name Margareta or Margarete has the primary diminutive form *Greta*, but apparently *[Gretl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gretl_Braun)* is attested as well.
>  **8. Expression of defeat**: *"I lose!"* / *"I lost!"*.  This is perhaps the most straightforwardly ambiguous (and least clever?) clue among these ten Down clues.
>  **9. European teeth**: *dents* / *denti*.  A huge stretch: *dents* is [the word for teeth in French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dents#French), while *denti* is [the word for teeth in Italian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denti#Italian).

Furthermore:

> **22-Across. "Who ___?", chant for 17-Across (maybe)**: *dey*.  "Who *dey*, who *dey*, who *dey* think gonna beat dem Bengals?! [Nobody!]" is a famous chant from Bengals supporters, now [frequently](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nfl/bengals/2022/02/01/who-dey-meaning-cincinnati-bengals-cheer-origin/9290815002/) [mentioned](https://www.citybeat.com/arts/uncovering-the-origins-of-the-cincinnati-bengals-who-dey-chant-12621521) in news articles because of the upcoming Super Bowl. This answer would only apply if Cincinnati was 17-Across.
>  **2-Down. Number of years Matthew Stafford has played for 17-Across (maybe)**: *one*.  Matthew Stafford is the current quarterback for the Los Angeles Rams, having been traded from the Detroit Lions last year.  This answer would only apply if Los Angeles was 17-Across.